# PHP crypt string

Tags: php, crypt

I try to crypt the sso ticket on my flash game.

```
var flashvars = {
"sso.ticket" : "<?PHP echo TicketRefresh($user['username']); ?>" };
```

This is the part of the code i've tried to encrypt it

```
function encrypt($pure_string, $encryption_key) {
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
$encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $encryption_key,
utf8_encode($pure_string), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
return $encrypted_string;
}

<?php
define("ENCRYPTION_KEY", "!@#$%^&*");
$string = TicketRefresh($user['username']);
$encrypted = encrypt($string, ENCRYPTION_KEY);
?>

var flashvars = {
"sso.ticket" : "<?PHP echo $encrypted; ?>" };
```

I am a beginner and I don't know what is wrong with it, thank you for your help.

Comment: `encrypt` isn't a php function, did you write it yourself maybe? If so can we see it?

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt is not a PHP function

`crypt` is one, that should be used with a salt for more security:

```
$encrypted = crypt($string, $longSalt);
```

I recommend you to use a `$longSalt` of random characters of 10 or more characters

Comment: Sorry I forget to put my function encrypt, i edited the post.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function encrypt() I probably made a mistake in syntax but I can't find where.

Comment: Your encrypt doesn't seem to be defined inside php tags.

Comment: well in fact I just search a method to crypt this "sso.ticket" : "<?PHP echo TicketRefresh($user['username']); ?>" }; (ticketrefresh allow user to connect after attribuate a new ticket). I want make this information harder to get to people who search it to exploide....